# how to delete a part of urls using javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I wanna know how to delete a part of urls using `javascript`
here's an example :

1.`bp.blogspot.com/-gAOB6nWGgT0/Vtmbryn-e-I/AAAAAAAAWG0/jE5iiKmzi0Q/**s72**-c/imga0343.jpg`

2.`bp.blogspot.com/-zO5IrZEk-ck/VthrVoL0H4I/AAAAAAAARBw/LvQFWENcVB0/**s72**-c/s7e.jpg`

3.`bp.blogspot.com/-dfwIePlSYWw/Vtl5w0YqmBI/AAAAAAAARC8/BOeebRHZWzA/**s72**-c/facema.jpg`

I wanna delete this part of urls  :`**s72**`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you scenario is, but If you just want to delete the **s72** from the url and use it elsewhere, it's as easy as

**javascript:**

```
var url = window.location.href;
var newUrl = url.replace(/\/s72-/, "/-");
//then if you want to navigate to the new url,
window.location.href = newUrl;
```